# Use of 'Dignified'

Tags: word-usage, single-word-requests

I have a doubt ! I'll be very thankful if anyone can answer it for me

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

I feel dignified right now.

Few responses will be I feel honourable that I acknowledge.  But can we feel dignified or not . I have been told that we can  only use this sentence like - I am dignified.  Saying that we feel dignified is incorrect.

I appreciate your time in replying to the question

Thanks

Comment: It is correct syntax and semantics, but it's not something that would normally be said.  "Dignified" is an attribute that is generally assessed by others, vs something that you can say about yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely you can say, "I feel [dignified](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/dignified?s=t)."

I imagine myself getting dressed in a tuxedo, looking in the mirror, standing up straight, grasping my lapels and saying, "I feel dignified."  I'd be suggesting that my elegant, majestic, mannered appearance has imbued me with a sense of dignity matching my appearance.

Comment: Agreed. But there are, of course, more humble ways of experiencing dignity - such as going to the aid of someone in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

“I feel dignified right now” is correct, although the word isn’t used too often to describe oneself. It’s used more often to describe someone else, like “The prince must act dignified at the party” or “The dignified man I saw wore a suit.”

Comment: Thanks for your time in replying.  Other than the common use,  is the usage correct ?